# AngularJS and Web Api Social authentication

Tags: c#, angularjs, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, asp.net-web-api

I need some help for authenticate my angularJS app and my rest api(WEB API) with external social logins( twitter, facebook, google, etc).

I'm working with Web-api and angularJS app(not spa project from Visual Studio, it's independent).

How I should do it if I want to authenticate via oauth through my backend, but having a confirmation to permission access at frontend?

Something like that but using authentification at my backend https://dev.twitter.com/docs/browser-sign-flow

Comment: Did you look at articles like this [one](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)?

Comment: I followed this article to the letter, and it's working well for me. It's long, but just be patient and work through it step by step!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a JWT to have an auth state on the front-end and you can use it to authenticate your calls to your back-end

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2013/11/7/json-web-token-the-useful-little-standard-you-haven-t-heard-about